# A subgroup of $S_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Show that the set of permutations $\{\sigma \mid \sigma(i)\le i \text{ for }1\le i\le 6 \}$ is a subgroup of $S_6$.

I am stuck at how I am supposed to reason about this question. I'd assume I'd first check closure, then the group axioms, but how am I to deal with the huge variety of choices of the image? Is there supposed to be a really obvious way to show closure that I am failing to see?

Comment: but are there a "huge" variety of choices? Can you take two **different** ones and show that the composition is there?

Comment: I'm not sure how to reason about this part. Consider $\sigma(i)$ first—we have $i$ choices. Now consider $\sigma(i<x≤6)$: we have ≤6-(i+1) choices and $\sigma(1≤x<i)$

Comment: How many choices do you have for $\sigma (1)$? Then, done that, how many choices do you have for $\sigma (2)$? Do you see what would happen?

Comment: ohhh, $\sigma(1)=1$, so then $\sigma(2)=2$ and $\sigma(i)=i$ is forced; it's just the identity

Comment: Indeed, just the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us call a permutation $\sigma$ good if $\forall i:\sigma(i)\le i$. Consider composition $\sigma\circ\tau$, where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are good permutations from $S_6$. Since $\tau$ is good, $\tau(i)\le i$. Since $\sigma$ is good, $\sigma(\tau(i))\le\tau(i)\le i$. Therefore, $\sigma\circ\tau$ is good. There is at least one good permutation, namely a trivial one. So good permutations form a subgroup.

The fact that there is only one good permutation could help, but we didn’t use it.

We used [the finite subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test) though.

Comment: Perhaps it worths mentioning that you have used the subgroup test for finite subsets of a group.

Comment: @citadel thanks for the remark, did that.

Comment: You haven't demonstrated the set in nonempty, an often overlooked condition for most subgroup tests.

Comment: @Shaun I did it on purpose, since id is obviously there. But I probably should have included it. Thanks for the suggestion.